# display all element in ArrayList<superclass> increase with salary

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, arraylist

I have an abstract class Staff has one property coefficient (of salary). I have two class Employee has own property is overTimes and Manager has one property is title extend from Staff and implements interface ICalculate has one function calculateSalary(). All object create from Employee and Manager, I add to ArrayList listOfStaffs. So after I calculate salary how can I arrange staff ascending with salary? Thank you
This is my Staff class

```
public abstract class Staff {

private double staffCoefficient;

public Staff(double staffCoefficient) {
    super();
    this.staffCoefficient = staffCoefficient;
}

public double getStaffCoefficient() {
    return staffCoefficient;
}

public void setStaffCoefficient(double staffCoefficient) {
    this.staffCoefficient = staffCoefficient;
}
}
```

This is my Employee class

```
public class Employee extends Staff implements ICaculator {

private int overTimes;

public Employee(double staffCoefficient) {
    super(staffCoefficient);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Employee(double staffCoefficient, int overTimes) {
    super(staffCoefficient);
    this.overTimes = overTimes;
}

public int getOverTimes() {
    return overTimes;
}

public void setOverTimes(int overTimes) {
    this.overTimes = overTimes;
}

@Override
public BigDecimal calculateSalary() {
    double salary = super.getStaffCoefficient() * 3000000 + getOverTimes() * 200000;
    BigDecimal bigSalary = new BigDecimal(salary);
    return bigSalary;
}
}
```

This is my Manager class

```
public class Manager extends Staff implements ICaculator {

private String title;

public Manager(double staffCoefficient) {
    super(staffCoefficient);
}

public Manager(double staffCoefficient, String title) {
    super(staffCoefficient);
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public BigDecimal calculateSalary() {
    Double salary = super.getStaffCoefficient() * 5000000;
    if (getTitle().contentEquals("Business Leader")) {
        salary += 8000000;
        BigDecimal bigSalary = new BigDecimal(salary);
        return bigSalary;
    } else if (getTitle().contentEquals("Project Leader")) {
        salary += 5000000;
        BigDecimal bigSalary = new BigDecimal(salary);
        return bigSalary;
    } else if (getTitle().contentEquals("Technical Leader")) {
        salary += 6000000;
        BigDecimal bigSalary = new BigDecimal(salary);
        return bigSalary;
    } else {
        BigDecimal bigSalary = new BigDecimal(salary);
        return bigSalary;
    }
}
}
```

I can display all staff with salary but I don't know how to arrange them. Please help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The superclass, i.e. `Staff` is abstract. Therefore it can declare that it implements an interface without containing methods that implement the interface methods. In other words, change `Staff` to the following:

```java
public abstract class Staff implements ICaculator {
    private double staffCoefficient;

    public Staff(double staffCoefficient) {
        super();
        this.staffCoefficient = staffCoefficient;
    }

    public double getStaffCoefficient() {
        return staffCoefficient;
    }

    public void setStaffCoefficient(double staffCoefficient) {
        this.staffCoefficient = staffCoefficient;
    }
}
```

Note that the only change I made to your code is in this line:

```java
public abstract class Staff implements ICaculator
```

I added `implements ICaculator`.

Now, since class `Employee` and class `Manager` are subclasses of `Staff`, they also implement interface `ICaculator` and since they are not abstract classes, they must implement the interface method `calculateSalary` (which they do in the code in your question).

Now you can create a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of `ICaculator` objects that contains both `Employee` objects and `Manager` objects. One way to sort the list is to implement interface [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html). The below code demonstrates creating the `List` and the `Comparator` and sorting that `List`.

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortStaffBySalaryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee(0.5, 10);
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(0.75, 2);
        Manager mgr1 = new Manager(0.8, "Boss");
        Manager mgr2 = new Manager(0.9, "Big Boss");
        List<ICaculator> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(emp1);
        list.add(emp2);
        list.add(mgr1);
        list.add(mgr2);
        Comparator<ICaculator> c = (s1, s2) -> {
            BigDecimal salary1 = s1.calculateSalary();
            BigDecimal salary2 = s2.calculateSalary();
            return salary1.compareTo(salary2);
        };
        list.sort(c);
    }
}
```